# Sending a file via AirDrop (iOS) and the recipient is not given the opportunity to accept/reject the file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, airdrop

I've made it possible to send a serialised object via AirDrop. I've added both a custom **Document Type** and an **Exported UTI**.

Sending and receiving the file is working just fine - in that the recipient can process and use the data as expected.

However, when testing this process between my devices the files are *automatically accepted* - the recipient isn't given the opportunity to accept/reject.

Normally, when sharing files via AirDrop the user is given the opportunity to accept or reject, so I'm wondering if I need to *do something* to ensure this happens? But, I haven't seen anything in Apple's documentation relating to this...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! This turned out to be a non-problem.

I've been testing the application using two of **my own** devices (iPhone and iPad). The key here is that the same user / Apple ID is signed into each device.

In this case, when sharing data using AirDrop files *are* accepted automatically. I confirmed this by sending a photo from the *Photos* app between the same devices and the same auto-acceptance was observed.

When expanding the test to use *someone else's* iPhone, data shared via AirDrop from my app did get the system's Accept/Reject dialog.

Nothing to code. Nothing to do.